# Laravel - chaining any method on any model instance results in an error all of a sudden

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok so all of a sudden my dev environment broke, I'll try to explain what happened in points:

- I was adding a new migration and a new model/controller, when all of a sudden my page didn't load anymore saying that I am trying to load a non-object.
- I went to inspect inside php artisan tinker, I tried to run a normal query similar to the one on the mentioned page like:
- `$p = Product::first();`
- `$p->mainCategory;` (which is a method on Product.php),
- Normally it would return an **instance of** `\App\Category.php` with all of its parameters (all relationships are defined and they were working correctly), but **instead** I got `null` returned;
- So I thought, maybe that product doesn't have a matching `Category`, but then I queried the database with the `category_id` available on the `Product` instance, and I found the database record.
- **Eventually**, I thought maybe the new migration broke the database somehow, so I deleted the database and imported an sql dump from the server (in the process I also made a `git reset --hard` to the previous commit, just to be sure everything is as it was).
- I tried the same query again, and I got `null` again.
- So right now, I can get database records for models, but I cannot for the life of me run any method available for that model instance, and of course I can't fetch any relationship.
- **IMPORTANT** (I think)
- When I run something like `$p->mainCategory()`, I am expecting an **instance of** a `belongsTo relationship`, **instead** I get an error:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mainCategory()'

- **MAYBE** this is the key to solving this issue, because if I try to chain any method on a model instance like above, I get that error.
- I don't know why it is treated as an instance of Query\Builder, it should be an instance of App\Product
- Here is where it gets **even weirder**, this happens to all of my models, except one that's called `Restaurant.php`, that's the only one that I can perform queries/add methods normally to its instace, All others are broken.
- Below I will put my `Product.php`, `Restaurant.php`, and the `products_table` migration as a reference.

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->pro_active == 2;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->{'pro_name_' . app()->getLocale()};
    }


    public function offer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne( \App\ProductOffer::class );
    }


    public function cats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( \App\ProductCategory::class );
    }


    public function mainCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\Category::class, 'pro_main_cat_id', 'id' );
    }


    public function subCat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\SubCategory::class, 'pro_sub_cat_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function subsubcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Subsubcategory::class, 'pro_sub_sub_cat_id');
    }
```

Restaurant.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class, 'restaurant_products');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\RestaurantOrder::class);
    }


    public function isAvailable()
    {
        return $this->status == 1;
    }


    public function isOpen()
    {
        return $this->open == 1;
    }


    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo ?? asset('setting/logo/2018-06-10.logo.jpg');
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        if ( app()->getLocale() == 'ar' ) {
            return $this->name_ar ?? $this->name;
        }

        return $this->name_en ?? $this->name;
    }
}
```

products_table migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('pro_special');
            $table->string('pro_active');
            $table->integer('pro_main_cat_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_sub_cat_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_sub_sub_cat_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_country_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_city_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_price');
            $table->integer('pro_discount_percentage')->nullable();
            $table->integer('pro_after_discount')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_image');
            $table->string('pro_name_ar');
            $table->string('pro_name_en');
            $table->string('pro_desc_ar')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_desc_en')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_small_desc_ar')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_small_desc_en')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_slogen_ar')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_slogen_en')->nullable();
            $table->string('pro_view')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }

}
```

As you can see they are all normal classes, they should function similarly, but for unknown reason, they just don't.

**Edit**

Here's `dd(Product::first());` :

```
App\Product {#907
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:29 [
    "id" => 4
    "pro_special" => "2"
    "pro_active" => "2"
    "pro_main_cat_id" => 2
    "pro_sub_cat_id" => 2
    "pro_sub_sub_cat_id" => 3
    "pro_country_id" => 5
    "pro_city_id" => 7
    "pro_price" => 0.45
    "pro_discount_percentage" => 0
    "pro_after_discount" => 0.0
    "pro_image" => "upload/product/1529115234.Bruot.jpg"
    "pro_name_ar" => "خبز عربي 6 أرغفة"
    "pro_name_en" => "ARABISCHES BROT 6 STÜCK"
    "pro_desc_ar" => "<p>خبز عربي 6 أرغفة</p>\r\n"
    "pro_desc_en" => "<p>ARABISCHES BROT 6 STÜCK</p>\r\n"
    "pro_small_desc_ar" => "الوصف عربى"
    "pro_small_desc_en" => "الوصف المانى"
    "pro_slogen_ar" => "خبز-عربي-6-أرغفة"
    "pro_slogen_en" => "arabisches-brot-6-stck"
    "pro_view" => null
    "user_id" => 0
    "prod_count" => 988
    "pro_keywords_ar" => ""
    "pro_keywords_en" => ""
    "pro_meta_desc_ar" => ""
    "pro_meta_desc_en" => ""
    "created_at" => "2018-06-14 06:46:34"
    "updated_at" => "2018-11-30 20:06:58"
  ]
  #original: array:29 [
    "id" => 4
    "pro_special" => "2"
    "pro_active" => "2"
    "pro_main_cat_id" => 2
    "pro_sub_cat_id" => 2
    "pro_sub_sub_cat_id" => 3
    "pro_country_id" => 5
    "pro_city_id" => 7
    "pro_price" => 0.45
    "pro_discount_percentage" => 0
    "pro_after_discount" => 0.0
    "pro_image" => "upload/product/1529115234.Bruot.jpg"
    "pro_name_ar" => "خبز عربي 6 أرغفة"
    "pro_name_en" => "ARABISCHES BROT 6 STÜCK"
    "pro_desc_ar" => "<p>خبز عربي 6 أرغفة</p>\r\n"
    "pro_desc_en" => "<p>ARABISCHES BROT 6 STÜCK</p>\r\n"
    "pro_small_desc_ar" => "الوصف عربى"
    "pro_small_desc_en" => "الوصف المانى"
    "pro_slogen_ar" => "خبز-عربي-6-أرغفة"
    "pro_slogen_en" => "arabisches-brot-6-stck"
    "pro_view" => null
    "user_id" => 0
    "prod_count" => 988
    "pro_keywords_ar" => ""
    "pro_keywords_en" => ""
    "pro_meta_desc_ar" => ""
    "pro_meta_desc_en" => ""
    "created_at" => "2018-06-14 06:46:34"
    "updated_at" => "2018-11-30 20:06:58"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
```

dd(Category::first());

```
App\Category {#907
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:11 [
    "id" => 2
    "cat_name_ar" => "        المواد الغذائية"
    "cat_name_en" => "   Lebensmittel"
    "cat_order" => "1"
    "cat_image" => "upload/category/maincat/1529112273.categ.jpg"
    "cat_restura" => null
    "cat_slogen_ar" => "المواد-الغذائية"
    "cat_slogen_en" => "lebensmittel"
    "status" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2018-06-10 09:26:24"
    "updated_at" => "2018-10-11 21:26:22"
  ]
  #original: array:11 [
    "id" => 2
    "cat_name_ar" => "        المواد الغذائية"
    "cat_name_en" => "   Lebensmittel"
    "cat_order" => "1"
    "cat_image" => "upload/category/maincat/1529112273.categ.jpg"
    "cat_restura" => null
    "cat_slogen_ar" => "المواد-الغذائية"
    "cat_slogen_en" => "lebensmittel"
    "status" => "1"
    "created_at" => "2018-06-10 09:26:24"
    "updated_at" => "2018-10-11 21:26:22"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Relevant route in routes.php:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', 'front\FrontController@index');
```

FrontController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\front;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Slider;
use App\HomeAdvert;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use App\Contact;
use App\Page;
use App\Country;
use App\City;
use App\Subcategory;

class FrontController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $sliders = Slider::orderBy('slider_order', 'asc')->get();
        $homeadvert = HomeAdvert::first();
        $homecategories = Category::where('status', '1')->orderBy('cat_order', 'desc')->with('products')->get();
        $homeproducts = $homecategories->map(function ($item) {
                                            return ($item->products()->limit(8))->get();
                                        });

        $homelatestproducts = Product::where('pro_active', 2)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take(8);


        $homecategorysearch = Category::where('status', '1')->orderBy('cat_order', 'desc')->get();
        $homecountrysearch = Country::orderBy('country_order', 'desc')->get();
        $pages = \App\Page::all();

        return view('frontend.layouts.index', compact('pages', 'homecategorysearch', 'homecountrysearch','homelatestproducts', 'homeproducts', 'sliders', 'homeadvert', 'homecategories'));
    }

}
```

Comment: No, the error is happening because it is treating $product as an instance of Query Builder, which makes sense, there is no mainCat() method on a query builder instance, but, this should be an instance of App\Product, which does have a mainCat(); method. (I edited the word in the error because it was written incorrectly, mainCategory() not mainCat())

Comment: The error quite evidently says you have not finished your query with `get()`, `first()` or `all()`... it is still a builder and no result. -- Personal recommendation on the side: you should use an extra table for field translations that allows for additional languages without having to change code. Your current database structure violates the first normal form.

Comment: what is returned from `get_class(App\Product::first())` in tinker?

Comment: Do you have data in the product table? Because there isn't first() method ll return null. Please check if you have data in the table.

Comment: @Namoshek If you read carefully, I specifically used Product::first(); as my query, as for the second note on the database I know that, I got hired while the application is already live, so right now it we're working on other things, but thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero Yes, Product::first(); returns a fully fledged \App\Product instance, the products table has 854 products.

Comment: @Amade The result is "App\Product"

Comment: Have you checked that there is no other broken call involved (e.g. view composer, middleware,...)? What about the stack trace?

Comment: @Namoshek The thing is I haven't changed a thing, and suddenly everything broke, and I am not sure what do you mean by "stack trace".

Comment: Maybe it's caused by some global scopes? What is returned from: `App\Product::first()->newQuery()`? I think it should be `lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Is it `lluminate\Database\Query\Builder` in your case by any chance?

Comment: My suggested sources of failure don't require changes, just utilization. A stack trace will help finding the location by telling you which file and line number an error originates from. The Laravel default exception page normally shows a stack trace. If you are not familiar with it, do some research. These are debugging basics.

Comment: No it is  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Comment: @Namoshek I was getting all of my errors from tinker, because the blade view didn't load because it had many "undefined variables" due to the original problem, none of the variables I assigned were loading, so when I tried to dd(Product::first()); for example. THE PAGE STILL LOADED, as if there is not dd(); at all..

Comment: @Namoshek So this is even weirder, when I try to dd() or die() from the controller, the page still tries to load, even though I commented out the return view() line...
It is still trying to load the nav and footer partials, as if the dd() is not there at all, it's completely ignoring the controller.

Comment: Sounds like your route is executing a different controller method. Use `php artisan route:list` to verify your routes are properly configured. Maybe they are cached? Clear all caches.

Comment: @Namoshek I am positive it is loading the correct controller and the correct method, because if I comment out that route, I get the 404.

Comment: Then please show us your whole controller with all relevant methods.

Comment: @Namoshek It's done.

Comment: I don't see any call to the `mainCategory` relation in your controller code. But as a side note, your line `Product::where('pro_active', 2)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take(8)` will suffer from bad performance because `take(8)` is executed in memory. `get()` will return a collection with all elements from this table. You should put `take()` before `get()` to perform the limit within the database.

Comment: The `$homeproducts` query respectively mapping looks weird as well...

Comment: @Namoshek I appreciate your notes, but they are not addressing the main issue, about the call for mainCategory, it was just an example so it's not in this controller, and I even removed all the dd() calls from the method as well, none of them works anymore for some reason...

Comment: Well, how are we supposed to help if the code and error you show us is not what causes the actual problem? This is not how Q&A debugging works...

Comment: @Namoshek Ok you want to help right? You have the route and you have the controller, right now, that controller is not responding to anything, what do you think I should do?, they view is getting returned regardless of what I do in the controller, and not a single query that includes a relationship is working, if I did dd(Product::first()->mainCategory)); rn in the controller, it won't do anything and the view will get returned.

Answer (score 0):

`first()` and `last()` method return an instance of the class, if there isn't they will return null.

You can do this validating the returned data

```
$product = Product::first(); // or last() for eg.
if($producto) { do something.... }
```

Or you can get all products with some condition and verify the result collection quantity

```
$products::where('field','somthing')->get(); //or all()
if($products->count()) { //or > 0 if you want
   do something...
}
```

Check if exists data in the product table, first.

Please try this and let me know how it works.

Comment: My database queries were working as expected up until some point, something triggered a breaking change in my dev environment, my products table has 854 products, there is data in all of the tables.

Comment: Could you paste here this result dd(Product::first());

Comment: Done, added to the question itself.

Comment: And dd(Product::first()->mainCategory); and maybe a dd(Category::first()); to see the structure.

Comment: The product looks good. Maybe there is some id missing in the category table. But i will see when you add others dumps

Comment: dd(Product::first()->mainCategory); returns null, dd(Category::first()); returns the category instance

Comment: Added dd(Category::first());.

Comment: Could you try this...  `public function mainCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Category', 'pro_main_cat_id', 'id' );
    }` the first parament is only the class name  as string